# Does flying saucer support pseudo elements

Tags: flying-saucer

I have been trying to add pseudo elements with content into the CSS for a page that is being converted with the Flying Saucer library. When viewing the page in a regular browser as HTML, the code works fine and I can see the pseudo element (:before). When rendering the PDF using Flying Saucer however, the pseudo element disappears.

According to the official Flying Saucer spec, CSS 2.1 is supported so that should include pseudo elements and content attributes. So why isn't it working for me? All other CSS is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flying-saucer supports the following CSS pseudo elements:

- `before`
- `after`
- `first-line`
- `first-letter`

It only supports the standard, double-colon CSS3 syntax (`::after`), and not the old, single-colon CSS2 syntax (`:after`).

Here is a working example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  div::before {content: "before - "}
  div::after  {content: " - after"}
  p::first-line   {font-weight:bold}
  p::first-letter {color:blue}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>A div</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed scelerisque augue. Nulla eleifend aliquet tortor, vel placerat velit fringilla vitae. Sed quis sem eu arcu dapibus convallis.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result (using flying-saucer 9.1.6):
[image: PDF showing pseudo element applied]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if I can use :first-of-type or similar selectors too?

Comment: Never mind, seems that this is part of the CSS3 spec and not 2.1

Comment: No, `first-of-type` is not supported. As far as I can tell looking at the source code of flying saucer, only the 4 pseudo-elements listed in the response are supported.

Answer (score 4):

Besides of CSS2.1 pseudo-elements listed in [the CSSParser](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/blob/e0d04b76d99af20acf93f3f5ebfc01c67bbd12bc/flying-saucer-core/src/main/java/org/xhtmlrenderer/css/parser/CSSParser.java#L57), which are:

- `first-line`
- `first-letter`
- `before`
- `after`

Flying Saucer supports following pseudo-elements for output rendering:

- `first-child`
- `even`
- `odd`
- `last-child`

Some browser related/interactive pseudo-elements are supported as well:

- `link`
- `visited`
- `hover`
- `focus`
- `active`

See the source code of [addPseudoClassOrElement](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer/blob/e0d04b76d99af20acf93f3f5ebfc01c67bbd12bc/flying-saucer-core/src/main/java/org/xhtmlrenderer/css/parser/CSSParser.java#L1161).